# What is the equivalent of Shift-Command-4 for video recording?

Tags: video, quicktime, video-capture

Is there an equivalent of Shift-Command-4 to select a specific window and then record all the mouse clicks and key strokes and action on that window only?

Having to select the area for recording with Quicktime or other tools is less elegant because it adds potentially unwanted screen around the target window.

[image: Shift-Command-5 Choices]

None of the choices from Shift-Command-5 (shown in the image) are what I am looking for.

I thought there might be an easter egg that is Shift-Command-4 but for screen capture video.

Comment: Is shift+command+5 sufficient for you?

Comment: @X_841 doesn't look like it records a window

Comment: Not any worse/better than shift+cmd+4. See my comment below

Answer (score 1):

HT @X_841 - [How to record the screen on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208721)

> Use the screenshot toolbar - [image: Use the screenshot toolbar]

Comment: This allows you to select a part of the screen but not select a particular window like shift+command+4 does.

Comment: Its nearly the identical interface if you select "record parts of the screen" in the bottom menu bar. You can just like with Shift+cmd+4 select the screen area you want to film, I dont really see the difference

Comment: There is a fine difference in recording one window precisely and one window and a bit of stuff around it. Professionally delivered videos don't have the bit of stuff around them and that's the experience I want to recreate.

Comment: go fullscreen and record that.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible for video capturing, just for screenshots with Shift-Command-5.

You can use [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com), a free software with lots of more settings.